# r programming: align two sequences of words

Tags: r, string, sequence

I want to align two datasets that mostly intersect on one column -- but each dataset is missing some rows.  For example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(word = c("my", "dog", "ran", "with", "your", "dog"),
                  freq = c(5, 2, 2, 6, 5, 10))
df2 <- data.frame(word = c("my", "brown", "dog", "ran", "your", "dog"),
                  pos = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "e"))
```

What I want as output is to have gaps inserted wherever there's a missing item.  Thus in the output, the new form of df1 will have NAs where df1 was missing a word match that was in df2, and the new form of df2 will have NAs where df2 was missing a word-instance that was in df1.

As in my example, the sequence matters and elements do repeat.  (so this isn't a generic "merge" situation.)  I suspect DTW could figure in to the solution but I'm not sure.  For present purposes it's fair to stipulate that only exact matches do match.

For the above case the desired output would be a data frame with these columns:

```
$word1 my NA dog ran with your dog
$freq 5 NA 2 2 6 5 2
$word2 my brown dog ran NA your dog
$pos a b c d NA a c
```

Thus, the sequence in each original data frame is maintained; nothing is deleted; word tokens remain tokens (it's a corpus, not a dictionary); all that's really happened is spaces (NAs) have been inserted where data are missing.

Answer (score 2):

```
df1$count = ave(seq_along(df1$word), df1$word, FUN = seq_along)
df2$count = ave(seq_along(df2$word), df2$word, FUN = seq_along)
df1$merge = paste(df1$count, df1$word)
df2$merge = paste(df2$count, df2$word)
output = merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "merge", all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE)
output[c(2, 3, 5, 6)]
#  word.x freq word.y  pos
#1   <NA>   NA  brown    b
#2    dog    2    dog    c
#3     my    5     my    a
#4    ran    2    ran    d
#5   with    6   <NA> <NA>
#6   your    5   your    a
#7    dog    2    dog    c
```

Comment: the sequence is not maintained though, and one of the dogs is missing...

Comment: in the real dataset each row is tagged with a consecutive ID number, and I'm finding that if I sort the output by df1's IDs, then the ID numbers of rows from df2 are not monotonically ordered.  This makes me suspect that some outputs are misaligned. I'm still working to understand this, but if I can't repair that, it's fatal (since the purpose is to correctly gather data for each token from each data source).  :|